# Generalized eigenvalues of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A, D \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric matrices and consider the following matrix pencil

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-I & A+\lambda I \\
A+\lambda I & -D \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If we already have the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$, what can we say about (or how to compute) the eigenvalues of the matrix pencil? And vice versa?

Comment: To have an idea what's a satisfactory answer, what would your answer be for $n = 1$?

Comment: Suppose that $P,Q$ are positive semidefinite complex matrices (possibly of different dimensions). Then a block matrix of the form
$\begin{bmatrix}
P & X \\
X^* & Q
\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite precisely when $X=\sqrt{P}K\sqrt{Q}$ for some $K$ with $\|K\|\leq 1$. For a reference, this is Lemma 3:18 in John Watrous's Theory of Quantum Information.